# ArrayObjects with more than one value?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Hey I have simple loop that im trying to create ArrayObject so that it holds a co-ordinate system.

I'm trying to reduce the amount of data held by placing the Y co-ordinate in the X co-ordinate to reduce duplicate data.

This is what i tried:

```
$object = new ArrayObject();
$xWidth=1;
$yWidth=2;

for ($x=0; $x < $xWidth; $x++) {
        $object[$x] = new ArrayObject();

  for ($y=0; $y < $yWidth; $y++) {
        $object[$x][$y];
   }
}
```

The problem is the data comes out not what i expected... this is how i see the data:

```
ArrayObject Object
(
    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => ArrayObject Object
                (
                    [storage:ArrayObject:private] => Array
                        (
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

Any idea how I can put the second Y numbers into the X ArrayObject?

Comment: `$object[$x][$y];` doesn't do anything.

Comment: change `$object[$x][$y];` to `$object[$x][] = $y;`

Comment: @WaleedKhan........ I know thats why im asking the question...

Comment: Is this a question about memory conservation? Then ArrayObject might not be the best choice.

Comment: @mario that and less iterations for lookups y will be dependant on X existing... why is this a bad choice

Comment: What is your overall goal @Dave?

Comment: @NicholasPickering to save the amount of data stored whilst have a X:Y co ordinate system that i can loop

Comment: @Dave so why use ArrayObjects instead of normal arrays?

Comment: @NicholasPickering Because to have arrays like: $array[$x][$y] is a problem when i want to loop the data, given a loop will start at 0 wouldnt that create a ton of undefined offsets

Comment: I think @youssDev's solution is the best one. You can loop throught the objects easily, you won't have to worry about offsets because your data isn't connected directly to the keys.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why don't you just use an object that include y and x

```
          class coordinates{

             public __constructor($x, $y){
             $this->x = $x;
               $this->y = $y;
              }
              private $x;
            private $y;
            public function setX($x){
            $this->x = $x;
            }

             public function setY($y){
            $this->y = $y;
            }

            public function getX(){
            return $this->x;
            }

            public function getY(){
            return $this->y;
            }

            }

            $cordinate  = new coordinates($x, $y);

            $collectionCordinates[] = $cordinate;
```